# Why is my car still shaking and making noise after i change the motor mount and transmission mount

Tags: chevrolet, noise, automatic-transmission, impala

I have a 2011 Chevy impala I put on a new transmission mount and motor mount but its still idling and jumping what should I do

Comment: one supposes that the issue is the motor running rough, not the mounts.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!